# How to design JSON parser Entity Objects for Currency Converter API with below Output

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I am writing an application to consume currency values from external API converter https://exchangeratesapi.io/ to convert one currency to another.

For ex., https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP is returning the below

```
{
"rates": {
        "GBP": 0.7614025599
    },
    "base": "USD",
    "date": "2019-12-05"
}
```

or https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=CZK&symbols=IDR  is returning the below

```
{
    "rates": {
        "IDR": 611.2869231372
    },
    "base": "CZK",
    "date": "2019-12-05"
}

If you notice the above two outputs, currency value pair supplied as an object and the key is
```

I wanted to create two DTO classes for the above output for JSON parser purposes.

***Converter.java***

```
class Converter {
    private String date;
    private RatesObject rates;
    private String base;
}
```

***RatesObject.java***

```
public class RatesObject {
    private String Currency;
}
```

Now the actual issue is the currency key is not a generic one and every time I consume the data with different currency, key inside rates object is returned with original currency value such as 'EUR' or 'USD' as I mentioned above. I know how to handle if the currencies are sent in an Array as shown below but its returned as an object.

```
{
    "rates": [{
        "IDR": 611.2869231372
    }],
    "base": "CZK",
    "date": "2019-12-05"
}
```

Any suggestions to handle such output ?

Comment: Try to use Map<String, String> instead of RatesObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes 2 solutions to handle this with `Jackson`, please see below. And because you have already knew the symbol (in request parameters), you can retrieve the value by its name.

**Solution 1**
Declare `rates` as `JsonNode`:

```
class Converter {
    private String date;
    private JsonNode rates;
    private String base;

    //general getters and setters
}


ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Converter converterGbp = mapper.readValue(jsonGbp, Converter.class);
System.out.println(converterGbp.getRates().get("GBP").asText()); //0.7614025599
```

**Solution 2**
Declare `rates` as `Map<String, Object>`:

```
class Converter {
    private String date;
    private Map<String, Object> rates;
    private String base;

    //general getters and setters
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Converter converterGbp = mapper.readValue(jsonGbp, Converter.class);
System.out.println(converterGbp.getRates().get("GBP").toString()); //0.7614025599
```

Comment: Thanks Lhchin. I used first solution and its working perfect.